# Wrote a very simple word guessing game in python where you are given a hint every-time you guess wrong but it does not work

Tags: python, loops

```
secret_word = "Banana"
guesses = ""
maximum_guesses = 5
number_of_guesses = 0
out_of_guesses = False
while guesses != secret_word and not out_of_guesses:
    if number_of_guesses == 0:
        guesses = input("Guess a word: ")
        number_of_guesses += 1
    elif number_of_guesses == 1:
        print("The object is edible")
        guesses = input("Guess again: ")
        number_of_guesses += 1
    elif number_of_guesses == 2:
        print("The object is yellow: ")
        guesses = input("Guess again: ")
        number_of_guesses += 1
    elif number_of_guesses == 3:
        print("The object is a fruit:  ")
        guesses = input("Guess again: ")
        number_of_guesses += 1
    elif number_of_guesses == 4:
        print("You're stupid ")
        guesses = input("Guess again: ")
        number_of_guesses += 1
    else:
        out_of_guesses == True

if out_of_guesses == True:
    print("You have lost")
else:
    print("you have won")
```

The only problem is that when you guess the word correctly the loop keeps going and does not recognise that guesses = secret_word. Therefore there is no way of actually winning the game and all users are doomed to fail. I was thinking it might be an issue with how information is inputed into the guesses variable by the user and therefore the guesses variable can't be compared to the secret_word but it seems to be written fine so idk.

Comment: Works for me. Are you sure you are guessing "Banana" and not "banana" or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine. However, one of the principles of programming is [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) - Don't repeat yourself.

Instead of writing your code like you have, try to avoid repetition. This makes your code easy to read, understand, and debug.

You can use lists to store the message to print on each turn.

```
secret_word = "banana"
hints = ["", "The object is edible", "The object is yellow", "The object is a fruit", "You're stupid"]
maximum_guesses = len(hints)
```

Then all you need to do is use the turn number to access the message from the list. You can also use a for loop to track whether the loop was broken or ended successfully.
Also, you probably want to compare the lowercase version of the word so that your program doesn't think that "banana" and "Banana" are different words.

```
for guess_num in range(maximum_guesses):
    if guess_num == 0:
        guess = input("Guess a word: ")
    else: # Print the hint and guess again for turn 2 onwards
        print(hints[guess_num])
        guess = input("Guess again: ")

    if guess.lower() == secret_word: # If correctly guessed, say so and break the loop
        print("You have won")
        break
else: # Loop wasn't broken, player lost
    print("You have lost")
```

See? So much more readable and therefore easy to figure out if anything is wrong!

Comment: Best feedback I could've asked for, now I'm conscious of my DRY coding and already working on other projects with that in mind. Thank you